# Exclude table in org-mode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

While I enjoy the table mode of org and love the way I can work with the data in these tables with eg Python or R I am currently stuck with a simple problem: How can I exclude the table from being exported?

```
#+TBLNAME: data
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
...
#+TBLFM: ...
```

While i do know where I would include the respective option when executing R code (here I write :exports results so that the source is hidden) and while I know that |: as an option should seal the deal:

```
#+OPTIONS:     H:2 num:t toc:t ::t |:f ^:t f:t tex:t
```

I still have my huge table in my document. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Embed your table inside a `COMMENT` block thus:

```
#+BEGIN_COMMENT

#+TBLNAME: data
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
...
#+TBLFM: ...

#+END_COMMENT
```

I use this method for defining tabular data which I then process to produce an exported diagram or plot.

Comment: And - yay! - it does not prevent references to this table from working (e.g. from SRC blocks)

Comment: Maybe this worked but it doesn't work anymore with bleeding edge org mode. Commented out content is just... out.

Comment: As the previous comment noted, this answer doesn't work in new versions of Org. The highest-voted (second) answer does still work.

Answer (score 11):

Another smart way is adding `:noexport:` tag to the section header which includes the data table.

`C-c C-q` (`org-set-tags-command`), input "noexport" tag at the section.

If you want to export again, `C-c C-q` and delete `:noexport:` tag.

```
* Data Section not for export                  :noexport:

#+TBLNAME: data
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
|------+------+------+------+------|
|    1 | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    |
#+TBLFM: ...

* Analysis Section

#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :results output :exports results :var tmp=data
tmp
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
: 1    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 6):

@Juancho's answer is nice if you want to exclude a specific table from export.  If you want to exclude all tables, you can simply set the `|:` option:

```
#+OPTIONS: |:nil
```

Note that the value *false* is to be denoted by `nil` not `f`!

This sets the variable `org-export-with-tables` whose docstring is:

> org-export-with-tables is a variable defined in `ox.el'.
> Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
> Non-nil means export tables.
> This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword,
> e.g. "|:nil".