# Exporting a single column of an org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I want to export (not sure if that's the right word) a single column of an org-table as text, with the elements separated by commas. Eg if the table is

```
| x  | y  |
|----+----|
|  0 |  1 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  4 |  5 |
|  6 |  7 |
|  8 |  9 |
```

I want to get the result `0,2,4,6,8`.

In this case I want the first column, but I'd like a solution that allows me to export any single column.

Comment: Can you use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22003051/4780877 solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function to get the desired column and create a string with all the values. For example:

```
#+name: tbl
| x  | y  |
|----+----|
|  0 |  1 |
|  2 |  3 |
|  4 |  5 |
|  6 |  7 |
|  8 |  9 |

#+begin_src elisp :var x=tbl col=0
(mapconcat (lambda (r) (number-to-string (nth col r))) x ",")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 0,2,4,6,8
```

`nth` selects the desired column for a row. In order to concatenate all into a string, the number must be converted to a string with `number-to-string`.

Finally, the above operation is passed to `mapconcat`, which will form the string with the desired delimiter.

If you don't want the actual table in the exported output, [wrap it inside a COMMENT block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10063/53).

Comment: Neat! So `x` is bound to the table, as a sequence, but what kind exactly (list of list ?)

Comment: Yes. List of (list or hline)